# Mat values are changed when I alter other Mat object

Tags: c++, opencv

When I copy a Mat object, the values in other Mat object changes unexpectedly. The change occurs between the two print statement. Why is this?

```
Mat flow;

calcOpticalFlowFarneback(u_prev, u_curr, u_flow, 0.5, 2, 20, 3, 15, 1.2, OPTFLOW_FARNEBACK_GAUSSIAN);
flow = u_flow.getMat(ACCESS_READ);

cout << "1 " << flow.ptr<Pixel2>(680,192)->x << endl;


Mat out_img;
resized_frame.copyTo (out_img);

cout << "2 " << flow.ptr<Pixel2>(680,192)->x << endl;
```

Output as following

```
1 164.812
2 8.42217e-21
```

Comment: What are the dimensions of the matrix?

Comment: flow becomes CV_32FC2 and out_img becomes CV_8UC3

Comment: Those would be the types, I meant how many rows and columns are there in the matrix?

Comment: They are 480(h) * 852(w)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameters for `Mat::ptr` are `Mat::ptr(int row, int col)` as mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#af774caab4a38c6f7890f3254ad71eccf). Since `flow` is a 480x852 matrix, `flow.ptr<Pixel2>(680, 192)` accesses an out-of-bounds row and reads memory outside the matrix. Most likely that memory location is assigned to a different variable in your program (which might be `out_img` in this case) which gets changed over time. It might even segfault on some platforms depending on the memory layout used by the compiler.

Comment: Thank you! That was it!